# Fixing mojibakes in UTF-8 text

Tags: python, utf-8, character-encoding, mojibake

I have a file with text in Portuguese in UTF-8. Somehow, who produced the file selected the wrong encoding, and the text is full of [mojibake](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mojibake):

```
IDENTIFICAÌàÌÄO instead of identificação
AndrÃ© instead of André
```

Automated tools do not see anything wrong with the file. I tried to fix it with [Python package ftfy](http://ftfy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) to no avail.
How can I fix this file, apart from replacing all incorrect characters manually?

Comment: "IDENTIFICAÌàÌÄO" is weird. Are you sure about that one? Do you have more examples like that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"AndrÃ©" instead of "André" is the Latin-1 interpretation of UTF-8 encoding.
You can fix it by inverting the encoding/decoding:

```
>>> 'AndrÃ©'.encode('latin-1').decode('utf-8')
'André'
```

All cases following this pattern can be fixed like that.

However, I can't explain the other case (with "Ìà" for "ç" and "ÌÄ" for "ã"), and therefore can't provide a solution.
If you can find a codec where "Ì", "à", and "Ä" have the codepoints C3, A7, and A3, respectively, then you can use this instead of Latin-1 for fixing the text.